# Liquibase <sql> command giving different result than running it directly in SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, liquibase

I've got the following table:

```
id: BIGINT
value: DOUBLE
test: VARCHAR
```

with the values:

```
id: 1
value: 0.99
test: ''
```

Running the following SQL comment in my postgresql shell I get a different result than if I run it within a Liquibase `<sql>` tag:

```
UPDATE myTable SET test=concat('value=', value);
```

If I run it directly in my SQL shell I get my value for test as `value=0.99` however if I run the same SQL command in a Liquibase `<sql>` tag I get `value=0.98999999999999999`

Obviously this is a floating point error but why is Liquibase giving a different result if I'm using `<sql>`? Shouldn't the results be identical?

Comment: What's exactly the SQL command for Liquibase between <sql> and </sql>;  
Also what's exactly the SQL command running in your shell;  
Can you do both of these without using any variables (e.g. `value`) and compare?

Comment: I'm running the exact same command in both: UPDATE myTable SET test=concat('value=', value)

Answer (score 0):

If you were executing the exact same SQL strings I would expect the same results. However, you are providing `value` as a variable whose type is being handled by Liquibase, so perhaps it's the Liquibase number parsing that differs compared to a raw query string including numeric literal executed by the database.

If you were to use something like: `value: '0.99'` along with `... SET test=concat('value=', CAST(value AS double precision))` may give the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. It looks like something within Liquibase is parsing the values. This is odd to me since the <sql> tag is suppose to allow direct sql manipulation without being affected at all by Liquibase...

Comment: But it's not direct because you didn't put the literal `0.99` in the `<sql>` string `</sql>` you're using values provided indirectly through a Liquibase variable. Odd that the CAST didn't make it the same.

Comment: My understanding is that anything in the <sql> tag is the same as if running it directly in the database shell. It just passes the command through. Unfortunately this is not happening and it seems to be trying to do something.

Comment: I misread the question. This `UPDATE myTable SET test=concat('value=', value);` is used in your shell. What happens if you run the exact same SQL string as the Liquibase <sql> in your shell? Perhaps it is the double parsing in the shell that's different.

Comment: They give different results. In the shell I get the varchar result 'value=0.99' whereas in Liquibase I get 'value=0.98999999999999999' it's a floating point issue no doubt but why is the behavior different in one and the other...

Comment: How are you providing the `value: 0.99` in Liquibase and in your shell? Could you input `'0.99'` rather than `0.99` at that point in either?

Comment: I'm pulling it from another column. Basically I'm taking a double column and pushing it into a varchar. In reality it's more complex but for the purposes of this question I isolated the issue to just the core portion. I also added 'value=' as part of the String concatenation so that any casting is consistent. The key is that I'm not manually setting the value but getting it from another column that already has data.

Comment: And the difference you see between shell and liquibase is when data is being pulled from the exact same source row with the double value and not just two similar rows that appear like '0.99' whose internal bit-patterns may be different?

Comment: Then the difference would have to be in the (rounding or formatting) properties of the database connection used by liquibase vs the shell.

Comment: That's correct. However I'm using the exact same connection URL. There is absolutely no other difference. Hence why I posted it here ;)

Comment: Unless you can think of any other possibility where the difference could exist, there's nothing apparent in what you've described so far.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's much appreciated. Unfortunately I have no answer either.